# Android Keystore : "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect."

Tags: java, android, keystore, corrupt, jks

I'm using Android Stuio 0.5.9 as IDE
My mac version 10.9.3

Formerly I use oracle java se7 for develop my applications but when I update my mac it gives some version error so I remove java 7 and install java 6 and solved it.

When I develop a app in java 6 there is no problem but 
When I want generate a apk from use Generate signed APK Wizard I have error like this:

`Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.`

I know my password is correct. I find my password using it -> https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wiki/HowTo

```
Start smart wordlist attack on key!!

Capitalize first letter
Current Pass: a || est. 0 Pass/Sec

Got Password in 0 seconds
Password is: aAd**** for alias medyasef_dijital_medya_********
```

**EDIT**

My java version : 1.6.0.jdk

**EDIT**

I realize my jks file is corrupted so I have to fix it. is there any chance for fix it ?

Sorry bad english.
How can I solve it, please help me.
Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2):

Jdk version may be incompatible. Try other a windows computer. 
And ran this comman.

```
keytool -storepasswd -keystore my.keystore
```